# AutoMapper Conditional Mapping Not Working With Skipping Null Destination Values

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, prefixes

Below are my classes

```
public class Student {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public long? CollegeId { get; set; }
      public StudentPersonal StudentPersonal { get; set; }
    }   

    public class StudentPersonal {  
      public long? EthnicityId { get; set; }
      public bool? GenderId { get; set; }  // doesn't exist on UpdateModel, requires PropertyMap.SourceMember null check
    }   

    public class UpdateModel{
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public long? CollegeId { get; set; }
      public long? StudentPersonalEthnicityId { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the AutoMapper config

```
Mapper.Initialize(a => {
    a.RecognizePrefixes("StudentPersonal");
}

Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateModel, StudentPersonal>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => src.PropertyMap.SourceMember != null && src.SourceValue != null));
Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateModel, Student>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StudentPersonal, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<StudentPersonal>(src)))                                
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => src.PropertyMap.SourceMember != null && src.SourceValue != null));
```

And the sample test case:

```
var updateModel = new StudentSignupUpdateModel();
updateModel.Id = 123;
updateModel.CollegeId = 456;
updateModel.StudentPersonalEthnicityId = 5;

var existingStudent = new Student();
existingStudent.Id = 123;
existingStudent.CollegeId = 777; // this gets updated
existingStudent.StudentPersonal = new StudentPersonal();
existingStudent.StudentPersonal.EthnicityId = null; // this stays null but shouldn't

Mapper.Map(updateModel, existingStudent);
Assert.AreEqual(777, existingStudent.CollegeId);  // passes
Assert.AreEqual(5, existingStudent.StudentPersonal.EthnicityId);  // does not pass
```

Has anyone gotten conditional mapping to work with prefixes? It works ok on the non prefixed object.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda you're passing to `opts.Condition` is too restrictive:

```
src => src.PropertyMap.SourceMember != null && src.SourceValue != null
```

In this property's case, `src.PropertyMap` is `null` every time (which you might expect, since there's no single property that maps to the destination nested property from the source object).

If you remove the `PropertyMap.SourceMember` check, your tests will pass. I'm not sure what impact this will have on the rest of your mapping though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The issue here is that there are fields on the destination side that don't exist on the source side, which caused an issue for me.  I edited the original example to illustrate. Thoughts?